# PyPDF2 cannot import pdf file header

Tags: python, header, pypdf

I use PyPDF2 to import pdf file in string into python. Problem is the top of the first page doesn't want to be imported (.getPage(0).extracText() misses the top part).

I guess that there is a header property but i cannot find its name and i couldn't find any information on the internet.

Do you know how to do or where i can find information ?

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 did you try?